# Laravel 5: Convert query builder to eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder, php-carbon

Is there a way to transform this query builder to eloquent?

```
$users = DB::table('connections')
        ->join('locations','connections.to_user','=','locations.user_id')
        ->join('users','connections.to_user','=','users.id')
        ->select(
            DB::raw("*, IF((
                    3959 * acos(
                    cos(radians(".$lat."))
                    * cos(radians(latitude))
                            * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(".$lng."))
                            + sin(radians(".$lat."))
                            * sin(radians(latitude)))
                    ) < ".$distance.",true,false) near,(
                    3959 * acos(
                    cos(radians(".$lat."))
                    * cos(radians(latitude))
                            * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(".$lng."))
                            + sin(radians(".$lat."))
                            * sin(radians(latitude)))
                    ) AS distance")
        )
        ->where('status',3)
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->get();
```

**Connection model**

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
{
  return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->diffForHumans();
}
```

Because using query builder is not possible to return the created_at attribute in "diffForHumans" of Carbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is `Carbon::diffForHumans`, you can just convert (cast) `created_at` to Carbon.

Some of the possible usage:

- `$dt = ( (Carbon) $row->created_at ) // Casting`
- `$dt = Carbon::instance($row->created_at)`

And I would suggest on keeping Fluent queries instead of converting to Eloquent, as Eloquent is really only good for simple CRUD and simple relations.

Hope this helps :)

EDIT More example:

```
/* $rows = (Fluent queries)->get() */

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row['created_at'] = Carbon::parse($row['created_at']);
}
```

Use a variation of the above if you want to continue using Fluent.

If you insist on using Eloquent for whatever reason, you cannot set 
an accessor that exist as an attribute in the model.

e.g.:

`getIdAttribute` will never be called because there's already 
`$model->attributes['id']`.

If instead you define a `getHumanCreatedAtAttribute`, it will be called
because there is no `$model->attributes['human_created_at']`

Comment: Yes, I always try to make my queries with eloquent and not with query builder but since I need to apply that cast you wrote in the Model the cast or the attribute conversion is not working (check my post edited)

Comment: +1 - This is what I was looking for using diffForHumans(). I agree, sometimes it's more efficient to use query builder instead of eloquent.